# Can we take Sitecore package from 9.2 and install in 9.3

Tags: sitecore-client

Will there be any issues if we take the Sitecore package from version 9.2 and install it in 9.3

Thanks

Comment: when you are saying Sitecore package, did you mean content tree items? or you mean some module zip package?

Comment: @Raman just the content and template items. No modules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to move items from one version to another via Sitecore package. A better approach would be to move through Unicorn or TDS.

Comment: I was able to do it..my concern here is will there be any underlying issues in the cms because of this?

Comment: @sai as long as your content and templates are not overwriting or changing default Sitecore items, there should not be any issues.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it works fine. We have moved the entire content from 9.0.2 to 9.3 as packages.

The other option you can consider is serialisation of items, serialisation will be much quicker compared to installing a package.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. While upgrading from 9.2 to 10 we actually made a lot of clean up to serialized items, thus we packaged content and templates etc. and then updated our serialization configs and reserialized teamplates, renderings and so on. However, if no clean up to be made, using serialization for intial templates/renderings creation is enough and then installing content packages as usual.